# Creating a JSON array starting with index 1

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to create a JSON array starting with index 1

Here is my code which picks the images from the websites

```
      $image_urls = array();

            //get all images URLs in the content
            foreach($get_content->find('img') as $element)
            {
                /* check image URL is valid and name isn't blank.gif/blank.png etc..
                 you can also use other methods to check if image really exist */
                if(!preg_match('/blank.(.*)/i', $element->src) && filter_var($element->src, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
                {
                    $image_urls[] =  $element->src;

                }
            }

            //prepare for JSON
            $output = array('title'=>$page_title, 'images'=>$image_urls, 'content'=> $page_body);
            echo json_encode($output); //output JSON data

 data.images gives the array bu it starts with 0
```

Comment: Prepend some dummy value to `$image_urls` before assigning it in the array. And then use from index 1.

Comment: There is no such thing as an array in javascript that starts with index of 1.  You can put an empty element in the `0` spot in the array, but that spot will still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$output = array();
$output['1'] = array('title'=>$page_title, 'images'=>$image_urls, 'content'=> $page_body);
echo json_encode($output); //output JSON data
```

Output would be:

```
{"1":{"title":(*page_title*),"images":(*img_url*),"content":(*page_body*)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_unshift`

```
$image_urls = array_unshift($image_urls,null);//add an element at the zeroth index
unset($image_urls[0]);//remove the zero index
```

Answer (score 0):

An single line solution to the image_url array:-

```
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$arr = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), $arr);
echo  '<pre>';print_r($arr);
```

Output :
Array

```
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
)
```